# Semicolon in echo php

Tags: php

i have code like this :

```
<?php
    echo '<a onclick="function(''.$some.'');">';
?>
```

how can it return html like this :

```
 <a onclick="function('some');">
```

Big Thanks

Comment: Just escape the quotes properly: `echo "<a onclick=\"function('$some');\">";`

Comment: how if echo is using `'` not `"`?

Comment: Or just do `<a onclick="function('<?php echo $some;?>');">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you quoted the string with single quotes, you have to escape them inside the string.

Simply add a backslash `\` before each single quote inside the string:

```
<?php
    echo '<a onclick="function(\''.$some.'\');"';
?>
```

Also you can do that in a few other ways like:

```
echo "<a onclick=\"function('{$some}');\"";
```

Double quotes lets you simply embed a variable instead of concating, but now you have to escape double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure what information you need but here's an overview...

You can use both single and double quotes when `echo`ing in php,

```
echo "Some text to echo"; // Some text to echo
```

or

```
echo 'Some text to echo'; // Some text to echo
```

If you want to echo the quote type used to encapsulate the string, escape it like,

```
 echo "Some text with an \"escaped\" quote"; // Some text with an "escaped" quote
```

Strings within double quotes will accept a variable inline,

```
$var = "variable";
echo "A string with a $var in it"; // A string with a variable in it
```

Whereas strings within single quotes need to be concatinated with variables,

```
$var = 'variable';
echo 'A string with a '.$var.' in it'; // A string with a variable in it
```

Check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php for full details and examples.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to write this variable within an opening and closing php tag.

```
<?php $some = "some"; ?>

<a onclick="function('<?php echo $some; ?>');">Click me</a>
```

This generates:

```
<a onclick="function('some');">Click me</a>
```